# Plot over a matrix plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a line through a matrix plot with matplotlib to highlight specific entries in the matrix. How can I create a line at positions that are consistent with the matrix indexes?

```
plt.imshow(matrix, cmap = cm.Greys_r)

ax2 = plt.axes([0,0,1,1], axisbg=(1,1,1,0))

x,y = numpy.array([[0.05, 0.1, 0.9], [0.05, 0.5, 0.9]])
line = lines.Line2D(x, y, lw=5., color='r', alpha=0.4)
line.set_clip_on(False)
ax2.add_line(line)

plt.show()
```

It shows a line over the whole figure. How can I map the global coordinates x,y to the matrix plot coordinates?
Thanks

Comment: `imshow(matrix, extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, max]` try to figure out what this means. Put different numbers for xmin, xmax and you'll get the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, you can add the line to the axes of the image:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.rand(100, 200)
matrix[30, 50] = 5.0
matrix[80, 150] = 5.0

plt.imshow(matrix, cmap = cm.Greys_r)

ax = plt.gca()

x,y = numpy.array([[50, 150], [30, 80]])
line = plt.Line2D(x, y, lw=5., color='r', alpha=0.4)
line.set_clip_on(False)
ax.add_line(line)

plt.show()
```

output:

[image]